# Basic Firebase Realtime Database Rules Error

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, firebase-console

I'm currently testing with an open set of Firebase rules that work...

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true,
        "messages": {
      ".indexOn": ["timestamp"]
         }
    }
}
```

But when I try to prepare for release and use rules that only allow users to read/write this is what I get...

Error saving rules - Line 2: Expected '"'.

```
{
 “rules”: {
 “.read”: “auth != null”,
 “.write”: “auth != null”
 }
}
```

These are basic rules I got from the firebase page.  What's the deal?

Answer (score 1):

Your second snippets uses so-called smart quotes, which are not valid in JSON. Replace those with simple (double) quotes to make the rules valid JSON, and be able to save your changes again.

Comment: {
  "rules": {
      ".read":'auth != null',
      ".write":'auth != null',
        "messages": {
      ".indexOn": ["timestamp"]
         }
    }
}

Now I get a parse error

Comment: NVM...  Double quotes worked..  Not single quotes

Comment: Oh right, JSON is double quotes only. So: `{ "rules": { ".read":"auth != null", ".write":"auth != null", "messages": { ".indexOn": ["timestamp"] } } }`